# Calculate grand total from different years

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I was wondering how I would go about calculating the grand total of a certain count base on a year parameter set up in SSRS. When a certian year is selected the previous counts from all the previous years would add up with the current count. Before I used a @year parameter in my stored procedure and it worked in SSRS but this time I want to try hardcoding it then just have a year parameter in SSRS.

Here's a sample of my code that I'm working with at the moment:

```
select
sum(MITotal.Count) as 'Yearly Count',
year(c_date) as 'year'

from 
(select 
    count(*) as Count,
    pol1.C_STATE,
    month(pol1.c_Date) as Month,
    year(pol1.c_ate) as Year,
    left(datename(mm, C_Date), 3) + ' ' + cast(year(C_Date) as char(4)) as MonthYear
    from contract pol1
    where 
        pol1.C_STATE='wa' 
    group by pol1.C_STATE,month(pol1.c_Date),year(pol1.c_Date), left(datename(mm, C_Date), 3) + ' ' + cast(year(C_Date) as char(4))) MITotal
    group by MITotal.Year
```

this would return:

```
2   2009
5   2010
6   2011
```

How would I go about adding onto the code so that whenever, I choose say 2010 as the parameter year it would add 5+2 or 2011 and it would add 5+6+2 as the grand total. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Sum on a CASE statement based on the year parameter like so:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN Year(c_Date) <= @Year THEN MITotal.Count END) AS 'Historical Total'
```

Comment: Is there any other ways of doing it without using @Year as a parameter inside my sp.

Comment: That depends on whether the year is calculatable or not. If the year is to be selected by the user you have no choice, you have to pass it as a parameter. If it is something like "every year before last year" then you could easily calculate it in the stored procedure.